# Scala Set: + vs. ++

Tags: scala, set

What is the different between + and ++ applying on a set?

```
scala> val set = Set[String]("a","b")
set: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(a, b)

scala> set + "c"
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(a, b, c)

scala> set ++ "c"
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Any] = Set(a, b, c)
```

The first return Set[String] while the second return Set[Any].
It looks like ++ is more general, but what exactly is the ++ additional value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [API doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Set) for Set's ++ method, you'll see it takes a GenTraversableOnce

```
scala> val c:GenTraversableOnce[Any] = "c"
c: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[Any] = c
```

That means that in this case:

```
scala> set ++ "c"
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Any] = Set(a, b, c)
```

"c" is a GenTraversableOnce[Any], and then the ++ method adds all the elements of that collection.

A better example would be

```
scala> set ++ "cd"
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Any] = Set(a, b, c, d)
```

(I suspect like many other answerers I just did a little fiddling in the Scala console to check and then double-check whether that's through an implicit conversion or not. Yes it appears it is.)

Answer (score 9):

This should make it clear:

```
 ( set ++ "c") contains "a"  // true; "a" is a String in this set.


 ( set ++ "c") contains "c"  // false, "c" is a NOT a string in this set.

 ( set ++ "c") contains 'c'  // true, 'c' is a CHAR in this set.
```

So `( set ++ "c")` yields a set that contains the original `Set[String]` with `"a"` and `"b"` and now also contains `'c'` which is a `Char` and hence the type of `( set ++ "c")` is now a `Set[Any]`.

The String `"c"` can be viewed as a traversable of `Chars`. And the `++` method on sets accepts traversables.

Comment: scala> set ++ "ca"
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Any] = Set(a, b, c, a)

Comment: Yeah, that's a `Set[Any]` of `"a"`, `"b"`, `'c'` and `'a'`.

Answer (score 3):

From [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Set)

It looks like `+` is designed to add elements directly whereas `++` is designed to add from another collection.

Perhaps the  `"c"` is converted into a collection, if so this method could be a little heavier since a temporary object is being created.

Answer (score 2):

Karthik T is right, String is (edit: implicitly converted to) a collection and therefore you can use the `++` here. As you can see, the resulting set is not of type `Set[String]` anymore, but if `Set[Any]`. That is because a `String` is a collection of `Char` and the common supertype of `String` and `Char` is `Any`.

Comment: Actually, String is not a collection per se, but there is implicit conversion that makes it so.

Comment: we can see this :scala> val s : Set[String] = set ++ "c"
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[Any]
 required: Set[String]
Note: Any >: String, but trait Set is invariant in type A.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >: String`. (SLS 3.2.10)
       val s : Set[String] = set ++ "c"

Comment: @om-nom-nom thanks for the clarification, should've mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out in your REPL for a clear difference

```
val set = Set[Int](1,2)

set + 3 //res0: = ...set[Int] = (1,2,3)
set + Set[Int](3,4)  //Type mismatch
set ++ Set[Int](3,4) //res5: ...set[Int] = (1,2,3,4)
```

If your adding Set to another set use `++`
If your adding element to Set use `+`